# How to get the url of voice message using in LINE Messaging API(bot)

Tags: line, bots

I have a wehook message of my bot like

"{"events":[{"type":"message","replyToken":"68e0e0e4832c4a648be53c05205300e1","source":{"userId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","type":"user"},"timestamp":1493294932887,"message":{"type":"audio","id":"6000684214622"}}]}".

In this webhook message there is an audio file id as"6000684214622". I need to download the audio file.So when I searching in the messaging api documentation , I got an API like "GET https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/{messageId}/content". When i using this API I got a binary file. So How can I get the url for downloading that audio file?

what type of audio format using in LINE bots?

Answer (score 1):

The type of audio format using in Line Bot is m4a(https://github.com/line/line-bot-faq#do-audio-files-have-to-use-the-m4a-file-extension).

If your webhook message look like

```
{
  "replyToken": "nHuyWiB7yP5Zw52FIkcQobQuGDXCTA",
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": 1462629479859,
  "source": {
    "type": "user",
    "userId": "U206d25c2ea6bd87c17655609a1c37cb8"
  },
  "message": {
    "id": "325708",
    "type": "audio"
  }
}
```

GET https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/{messageId}/content

By use line-bot-sdk-nodejs

```
const line = require('@line/bot-sdk');

const client = new line.Client({
  channelAccessToken: '<channel access token>'
});

const stream = client.getMessageContent('<messageId>');
stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
  ...
});
stream.on('error', (err) => {
  // error handling
});
```

When you can get a file, just save the file with the .m4a extension.

Comment: Does this still work? I seem to only get 404 respones when trying to retrieve audio and image content via `getMessageContent()`.

Comment: change api to api-data in the domain name

Answer (score 1):

For whoever is stuck on this, you can use this endpoint:

GET [https://api-data.line.me/v2/bot/message/{messageId}/content](https://api-data.line.me/v2/bot/message/%7BmessageId%7D/content)

{messageId} is the id of the media file you've received.
Here's an api reference:
https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/#get-content

Answer (score 0):

`getMessageContent` example

```js
const fs = require("fs");

function storeFileByMsgId(event, path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.getMessageContent(event.message.id).then((stream) => {
            stream
                .on('error', reject)
                .on('end', () => resolve())
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
        }).catch(reject);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).